# MySql query to count song votes in music chart

Tags: mysql, sql, voting

I have 4 tables for a music voting site.

1. Songs -id.
2. Charts - id.
3. Chart_song - id, song_id, chart_id. (join table)
4. votes - id, song_id_fk, chart_id_fk.

I want to count how many votes each song has for a particular chart (id = 4)

Here is how the vote table looks when people vote for a song (id = 1) to chart id (4)

```
id    |  song_id_fk  |  chart_id_fk |
 1    |    1         |     4        |
 2    |    1         |     4        |
```

Hopefully u understand. Please help. If I pass `'WHERE chart_id_fk = 4'`, I want to get a count of 2 for `song_id_fk = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like

```
select count(*) as vote_count, song_id_fk, chart_id_fk from votes group by song_id_fk, chart_id_fk
```

Comment: lol how did you do that? Fantastic, thanks. And its not even cumbersome. I guess my early tries were missing 'group by song_id_fk'. Thanks again.

Comment: If I saved your day vote me up ;).

Comment: yep but I need 15 reputation ._.